# Latest ADT doesn't allow typing values for width and height

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

I just got the latest ADT and have found that I can no longer type width and height values for layouts. It has a drop down which lets me select fill, match and wrap but I can't type numbers in for dip values etc.

Is this an intentional change by Google to encourage the use of an alternative method, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Possibly intentional to encourage the use of values in resource files (xml files). However, in the XML layout view you can still change the value no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an acknowledged bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33978) in the ADT plugin. The workaround is to edit the values in the XML directly.

Comment: I thought it might be, it's a bit of a major flaw when one is trying to create and edit layouts at the rate I am. I hope they fix it VERY soon.